# How to mock a local instance of a method with mockito Junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following method in the class CertainBean:

```
public boolean isOn() {
        InterfaceBean Bean = getBean();
        return Bean.hasBeenSetOn(Param1, Param2);
    }
```

Now I would like to

```
assertEquals(CertainBeanInstance.isOn(),true);
```

In order to do that I need first to mock IntefaceBean. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The constructor of CertainBean does not take an InterfaceBean, so no way of injecting a mocked one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use spy from Mockito 1.8 and mock only the method getBean

```
CertainBean bean = spy(new CertainBean());

when(bean.getBean()).thenReturn(yourInterfaceMockedBean);
```

there is more information about mocking real partial objects in this useful link:
http://blog.javabien.net/2009/06/21/mockitos-partial-mocks-testing-real-objects-just-got-easier/

and here the changes on Mockito 1.8
https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/ReleaseNotes#Changed_in_1.8.0_(23-07-2009)